# OCaml: int_of_string error

Tags: ocaml

I am a newbie to OCaml and I need to create an executable to be run on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows machines. [64-bit graphical installer of OCaml](https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/installation/) only generates executable for 64-bit machines (I think) and it works fine.

When I use [32-bit graphical installer of OCaml](https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/installation/) and compile the project with 32-bit version of OCaml, I get following error while I run the executable:

```
Fatal error: exception Failure("int_of_string")
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are asking to convert a string to an int, but the string denotes a value that's too large to fit into a OCaml int on a 32-bit system. On a 32-bit system, an int has 31 bits of space for the value. Without more information, it's hard to say more than this.

If you compile with the `-g` flag, you can ask for a traceback by setting the environment variable `OCAMLRUNPARAM=b`. This should give some more detail on where things are going wrong.

You don't say what kind of system you're running on. If you are running your program from the command line on a Unix-like system you can set `OCAMLRUNPARAM` like this:

```
$ OCAMLRUNPARAM=b  myproject arg1 arg2
```

Comment: The system I'm running on is Windows 10.

Comment: Here is a page that gives two ways to set environment variables on Windows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776899(v=vs.85).aspx. I am not a Windows user, so forgive me if this isn't a useful reference for your case.

Comment: I applied what you said and found that my problem occurs at the statement `@ [Data(int_of_string("0xFFFFFFFF"), "arg1")]`

Comment: Indeed, the value 0xFFFFFFFF is too large to fit into an OCaml int on a 32-bit system. There is a type int32 that can hold the full range of 32-bit values.

Comment: @yildizabdullah: And by the way an `int` on a 64-bit system is 63 bits long. So even though the 64-bit one happens to work so far, you might also want to examine your code for 64-bit systems and see if it's possible for it to have integers that use all 64 bits, and if so, consider using `int64` (or use `nativeint` which uses the right type for 32-bit or 64-bit systems).